# Android: add a MultiChoiceModeListener interface to a Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, multipleselection

I have a RecyclerView list with multiple CardViews.  I want to be able to select multiple CardViews with a longpress or a checkbox so they can be removed from the list in a batch delete method.  For a ListView or GridView the interface is implemented with "AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener".  Does RecyclerView have a corresponding interface or can the ABSListView Listener be used on the RecyclerView?